# Testing a void method with Mockito

Tags: java, mockito

I have a method like this:

```
public void someMethod() {
  A a = new A(); // Where A is some class.
  a.setVar1(20);
  a.someMethod();
}
```

I want to test 2 things:

1. The value of `Var1` member variable of a is 20.
2. `someMethod()` is called exactly once.

I have 2 questions:

1. Are those test objectives correct or should I be testing something else ?
2. How exactly do I test this using Mockito ?

Comment: You should read a [Mockito tutorial](https://code.google.com/p/mockito/).

Comment: 1 if this is your method's contract - yes, you shuld test it; 2. there is no way to intercept object creation in mockito - try to change your design (f.e. to use a factory for creation, and then just mock a factory call) or use another mocking framework (Take a look at JMockit, where a constructor call is just like any other method call)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't test that using Mockito, because Mockito can't access a local variable that your code creates and then let go out of scope.

You could test the method if A was a injected dependency of your class under test, or of the method under test

```
public class MyClass {
    private A a;

    public MyClass(A a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    public void someMethod() {
        a.setVar1(20);
        a.someMethod();
    }
}
```

In that case, you could create a mock A, then create an instance of MyClass with this mock A, call the method and verify if the mock A has been called.

With your code, as it is, the only way to test the code is to verify the side effects of calling `someMethod()` on an A with var1 equal to 20. If `A.setVar1()` and `A.someMethod()` don't have any side-effect, then the code is useless: it creates an object, modifies it, and forgets about it.

Answer (score 2):

Use JB Nizet's advice but note that order is important to you:

When verifying and order is important, use:

```
A mock = mock(A);

new MyClass(mock).someMethod();

InOrder order = inOrder(mock);
order.verify(mock).setVar1(20);
order.verify(mock).someMethod();
```

(Testing for exactly one invocation is the default in mockito).

## Caution

This kind of test will be tightly coupled to the implementation. So do this in moderation. In general aim for testing *state* rather than *implementation* where possible.

Answer (score 1):

Ad 1) Testing setters usually doesn't make much sense, but if you want to to then surely you have a getter on `A` to verify that `var1` is set to 20?

Ad 2) You can use `@Spy` and `verify()` to test invocations on methods.

```
A spy = spy( a );
verify( spy , times( 1 ) ).someMethod();
```

Your example code is a bit terse, so my answer is very general - hope you can work with it.

Cheers,