# Get a value of a local variable from a void function using mockito

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito

I have a method like below:

```
public void process {
   ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<>();
   ...
   ...
}
```

`data` is a local variable, the value of which I want to access after calling `myObject.process()` inside the test function. Is there any way I can do that?

Comment: You can't. And you needing access to local variable of method in test case means your test case is tightly coupled to your method implementation, which should not be the case. You should be refactoring `process` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mockito cannot access a local variable which is created by your code. The only way to test the code is to check whether something else is being effected by that variable and verify that change. This answer should help you out.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/30188745/17052051